# In a wordpress title, how can I combine the inverted breve ◌̑ (hat) with γ like with E it is Ȇ?

Tags: html, wordpress, unicode

I'd like to write a gamma having a hat on it into the title of a Wordpress blog post. Wordpress supports LaTeX but only in the body of a post, not in the title. So, in the body, I can write $\hat\gamma$ but I can't write it on the title. I've checked Wikipedia's [Combining_character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) article but I can't understand how I combine a character U+03B3 (&947; or γ) with the character U+030x (&770; or ◌̂). What should I write down to produce a γ and a hat above it?

Comment: Find a page with it (e.g. Wikipedia) an copy the character. Or just get a script with `\u03b3\0302`. Note: not all fonts supports all combinations of combining char, but most should have some fallback method, so they should display enough good approximation of such combination.